# Form is submitted, without me allowing it in JQuery. Play Framework-2.0

Tags: jquery, playframework-2.0

```
<form action="/settings" method="POST">
   <ul style="list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="slashdot.org -- http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot" checked=""><b style="padding-left:15px;">slashdot.org -- http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot</b></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="postimees.ee -- http://www.postimees.ee/rss/" checked=""><b style="padding-left:15px;">postimees.ee -- http://www.postimees.ee/rss/</b></li>
   </ul>
   <div>
       <button class="btn submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="sources" id="sources" class="sources" value="">                
</form>
<script>
    var feedValue="";
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        if($('this').prop('checked',true)){
            feedValue = feedValue + '+' + $('this').val();
            console.log($('this').val());
        };
    });
    $('#sources').attr('value',feedValue);
    alert("done");
});

</script>
```

So the problem is right now, that I am trying to get the values of the checkboxes that are checked and put them all into one string with + chars as separators. The problem is that JQuery will not replace the value of that hidden input field and it also submits the form even though I have currently omitted that line from code.

Does anyone have any kind of idea what is the problem?

Edit: By adding the $('form').submit() I get the result: +undefined+undefined, even though I have values for these checkboxes.

Comment: don't you need an event.preventDefault(); to disable the default behaviour of the form? (the POST in this case)

Comment: Why are you trying to put the values of the checkboxes into the hidden input?

Comment: If you want to intercept the `submit` use `$('form').submit()` (not `click()`) and return `false` from the function.

Comment: by adding $('form').submit(function(){ //the function//}) I now get the result: +undefined+undefined. Even though there are values in checkboxes.                                                  I am trying to put these values there so the Form I am using in Play could pick it up and I could modify the results in Java.